# "when, thenReturn" not recognised

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito

I'm mocking my service object as follows:

[image]

However, Intellij is not resolving the keyword `when`. I'm not sure what it can be. I've added all the correct dependencies in my build definition. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I could be mixing up my testing frameworks, but don't you need `test("Creating a list of tags should...") in { ... }`? Could `when` maybe not be defined in the context you have?

Comment: Yep, I needed to `import org.mockito.Mockito._` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing import:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito._
```

Comment: Side note: I dislike that ScalaStyle complains about `._` imports when they're so common.

Comment: Yeah, I thought by mixing in MockitoSugar it would have resolved everything but obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

Please `import org.mockito.Mockito._` as suggested by @Mika'il, but if you still are not able to resolve the issue check if you have an `org.scalatest.GivenWhenThen` import somewhere and check if you're probably extending it in your test class/base test class. Remove that. `org.scalatest.GivenWhenThen` trait has a different implementation of `when` method.